# How to change time zone for all outputs?

Tags: functions, date-and-time

How to change the time zone in *Mathematica* for all functions returning a date or time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for all functions that have the option [`TimeZone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeZone.html?q=TimeZone) is [`$TimeZone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$TimeZone.html). Setting it to a different value should change it for all these functions.

```
Unprotect[$TimeZone]
$TimeZone = -0
Protect[$TimeZone]
```

Sets the time zone to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).